# Is it possible to conditionally execute statements based on the translating engine, within Plain TeX?

Tags: pdftex, tex-core

Note that this question is about Plain TeX, **not** LaTeX. Consider the following example.

```
\pdfpagewidth 8.5 in
\pdfpageheight 11 in

foobar
\bye
```

Under `pdftex`, this will work fine. However, this will throw the following nasty error if I try to run `tex` on it.

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \pdfpagewidth
                  8.5 in
```

Is it possible to write my document so that it will not execute those two lines if it is running under `tex` rather than `pdftex`?

Comment: `\ifdefined\pdfpagewidth\else\newdim\pdfpagewidth...\fi` IIRC, `\ifdefined` is from eTeX, so wouldn't work on actual TeX.

Comment: Note that the format here isn't really important: you can do engine conditionals in LaTeX or plain (or others as appropriate)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `tex` executable runs the “original Knuth TeX”, whereas `\pdfpagewidth` is a `pdftex` primitive.

The usual

```
\begingroup\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup
  \expandafter\ifx\csname pdfpagewidth\endcsname\relax
  \else
    \pdfpagewidth 8.5 truein
    \pdfpageheight 11 truein
  \fi
```

will do. After it, `\pdfpagewidth` and `\pdfpageheight` will not be defined if they weren't to begin with.

Note that there are some LaTeX packages that can be used also with Plain TeX. Of these you could consider `ifetex`, because a distinctive feature of Knuth TeX is not having e-TeX extensions. So you could do

```
\input ifetex.sty
```

and do

```
\ifetex
  <code for non Knuth TeX>
\else
  <code for Knuth TeX>
\fi
```

The `<code for non Knuth TeX>` may distinguish from PDF and DVI output by using

```
\input ifpdf.sty
```

and the provided `\ifpdf` conditional. There are also `ifxetex.sty` and `ifluatex.sty`; all of them can be loaded in Plain with `\input if<...>.sty`.

There's also the “all-in-one” package `iftex.sty`, but its implementation is really basic with respect to `ifpdf`, `ifxetex` and `ifluatex`. It doesn't provide any way for checking e-TeX extensions.

Comment: One should note that there are several LaTeX packages for this (like `ifluatex`, `ifpdf`); some of these also work with plain.